Creating/opening Youtube stream/broadcast with API
I know that creating/opening Youtube stream/broadcast is possible through API. So i only need to create/open it. Is it free of charge? If not, what is the price?
Only prices I have found is something related to time of playing etc. and I dont know how is it relevant and related to creating them.
Thank you in advance

I believe you can accomplish this with the videos.insert() operation:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert
Per the docs, this operation has a quota cost of 1600 credits.
You get a certain quota per day for free. The details are given here:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota
If you exceed your API quota, you can request additional quota using their extension form (linked on the above page). It doesn't mention any cost in the documentation. My guess is they would charge you if your quota requirement is enormous, but I haven't had to file for an extension yet (I'm uploading 1-2 videos a day).
You can see your quota details in the Google Developer Console
https://console.cloud.google.com/
